# In HoTT, does $\prod_{T : \mathcal{U}} T \to T$ have only one element?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In Homotopy Type Theory, I can define

$id : \underset{T : \mathcal{U}}{\prod} T \to T$

by

$id(T, t) \equiv t$

But, are there any other elements of $\prod_{T:\mathcal{U}}T \to T$ ? I have been able to prove the following weaker statement with path induction:

Given $f: \underset{T : \mathcal{U}}{\prod} T \to T$

$proof : \underset{A, B : \mathcal{U}}{\prod} \underset{p : A = B}{\prod} \texttt{idtoequiv}(p) \circ f(A) = f(B) \circ \texttt{idtoequiv}(p)$

by

$proof(A, A,refl) \equiv refl$

So that if $T : \mathcal{U}$ and $e : T \to T$ is an equivalence, then $proof(T, T, ua(e)) : e \circ f(T) = f(T) \circ e$

Essentially, this is saying that for  any such function $f$, $f(T)$ must commute with all equivalences on T. This is enough to prove (at least informally, I don't know about in type theory) that $f$ is the identity on any set except for the two element set. But what about general types?

Comment: Your formula doesn't make sense. Is the type $T$ fixed?

Comment: @Berci T is fixed in the last two paragraphs. I edited to make this clear. In other locations, T is bound by the $\prod$

Comment: Ah, it's $\prod_{T:\mathcal U} \, (T\to T)$, sorry, my bad, I parsed it as $(\prod_{T:\mathcal U} T) \to T$.

Comment: I guess anyway, that one can set up a model for HoTT where this product type has many elements..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to construct, inside of type theory, an inhabitant of this type that is provably different from the polymorphic identity function.  This is a metatheoretic fact known as [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity).

On the other hand, it is not possible to prove *inside* of type theory that the identity function is the only element of this type, because as Berci says in the comments, there are models in which it has other elements.  In particular, if excluded middle holds (such as in the simplicial set model of univalence), then one can define (internally) such a function to swap the two elements of the two-element set and be the identity everywhere else.  In fact the converse also holds: if there is an element of this type that is not the identity on the two-element set, then excluded middle holds.  This and various other facts about similar parametricity principles are proven in the paper [Parametricity, automorphisms of the universe, and excluded middle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05617) by Booij, Escardo, Lumsdaine, and myself.

Comment: Very interesting. But, since excluded middle is provable false in HoTT, doesn't this prove that the function must be the identity (at least on 2)? Or did you mean excluded middle only on propositions?

Comment: By "excluded middle" I don't mean the version that is provably false in HoTT, but the sensible one that applies only to propositions and is consistent with HoTT (as I mentioned, it is true in the simplicial model).  See chapter 3 of the HoTT Book.